Как применить математический анализ при определении значения предлогов "кроме" и "помимо"?
Как известно, с этими предлогами много проблем, так как они могут обозначать как включение, так и исключение. Обычно начинаются долгие разговоры  о контексте, о чувстве языка и т.д., но определенности так и нет. Поэтому я предлагаю применить простейшую математическую модель: множество и его элементы. Она доступна всем, а решение задачи получается очевидным и однозначным.
ТЕОРИЯ

Если названо полное множество, то предлоги  кроме и помимо имеют значение исключения элемента из названного множества. Этот вариант встречается не так часто.

Контрольный примеры: По завещанию граф всё имение, ПОМИМО прямых наследников, отдавал Пьеру. Все принимали участие в разговоре, КРОМЕ Кити и Левина. Тут, КРОМЕ небольшого столика, не было никакой мебели.

Если названы оба элемента множества, то предлоги кроме и помимо имеют значение включения их в какое-то общее, но не названное в тексте множество. Этот вариант более частотный.

Контрольный примеры: КРОМЕ старика, в этот день приходило к нам ещё двое (все приходившие).
КРОМЕ трубки, у вас, может быть, есть и папиросы (все необходимое)?  Многие, ПОМИМО винтовок, были вооружены автоматами (все оружие). У меня с ним, ПОМИМО ВСЕГО, есть личные счёты (много претензий).
ПРАКТИКА
Применяем модель к вопросу, где было много споров, но остались сомнения:  Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов(,) кроме/помимо этих кленовых листочков. Здесь получается однозначное включение обоих элементов в общее неназванное множество (предметы для композиции).
Сравнить: Для этой композиции подойдут разные предметы, кроме кленовых листочков. Здесь значение исключения при названном общем множестве.
И никаких споров и рассуждений. Но правильно ли это?
ВОПРОС
Я не математик и могу ошибаться. Если вы разбираетесь в такой несложной математической логике, то проверьте, пожалуйста,  правильность рассуждения. Мне это нужно для языкового анализа этой важной практической проблемы в правописании.
Спасибо.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Еще один пример для оборота с предлогом кроме: включение или исключение?
Как известно, в современных правилах обособление обоих оборотов факультативно, но раньше обязательным было обособление оборотов со значением исключения. Актуализация этого оборота понятна: следует особое  внимание обратить на то,  что исключается. Сейчас это просто может учитываться наряду с другими факторами.
Это мой ответ  из другой темы:
 Пример другого необособленного оборота со 
 значением **исключения** (= не считая нас, 
 исключая нас) в распространенном предложении:
 Затем мы оказались в комнате свиданий.  Кроме нас 
 там было шестеро посетИтелей, заключённых отделял 
 стеклянный барьЕр. [Сергей Довлатов. Наши (1983)]

Правильно ли определено значение оборота, а то сейчас я уже сомневаюсь в этом (помог математический анализ). И очень интересная дискуссия в комментариях)) Там "очень простой" союз кроме назван коварным.
